In a Next.js project using TypeScript are types automatically detected?
Learning Next.js 14 and TypeScript the typical TypeScript approach I've seen is to create a types directly with an index.d.ts file and reference all types within that file.
Personal preference I'd like to isolate types as to not compound the index file with more than 200 lines of code so I created an area for types, example:
./root/types
  User.d.ts
  Dashboard.d.ts
  Pages.d.ts

and then in my tsconfig.json I have:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./*"],
      "@types/*": ["./types/*"],
    }
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", ".next/types/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}

Using "typescript": "^5"
Research

The best proper type for store in Next.js project + TypeScript
Interfaces vs Types in TypeScript
Live Typescript Checking with Next.JS
How to detect all Typescript and ESLint errors in NextJS project, not just in opened files?
How to add TypeScript types to request body in Next.js API route?
Do I have to reference TypeScript definition in every file?

After researching I didn't find an answer so I wonder with this approach should I be importing each type file into an index.d.ts then re-export or is that not needed?
Do I need to still import that type into the file I'm using even if the directory is added to config paths though I've read and watched TypeScript is sometimes auto-detected in a project?

In ts/tsx you barely define types globally, normally unless it’s an api types. Then it’s really doesn’t matter make them globally available, or import by place. When you import it’s probably easier to maintain

You wrote "the typical TypeScript approach I've seen is to create a types directly with an index.d.ts file" and I would disagree. The typical typescript approach is to write the code in typescript. A runner up is to author in javascript with jsdoc types inline. The eventual artefact and how the types get distributed is a detail left to the build step and not usually something anyone micro-manages. I think what you've seen is types retrofitted to existing javascript source code - a feature to support legacy projects not authored in Typescript. Don't do this to yourself in a learning project :)
